# How to add/remove x86 instruction in linux executables without spoiling the alignment

Tags: linux, x86, executable, binaryfiles

I'm new to binary and assembly, and I'm curious about how to directly edit binary executables.  I tried to remove an instruction from a binary file (according to disassembled instructions provided by `objdump`), but after doing that the "executable" seems no longer in an executable format (segmentation fault when running; `gdb` cannot recognize). I heard that this is due to instruction alignment issue. (Is it?)

So, is it possible to add/remove single x86 instructions directly in linux executables? If so, how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you ask? Why can't you change the assembler or relocatable object `.o` files instead?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Why can't I ask? Something that's not interesting to you may appeal to others. Moreover, nothing is always useless.

Comment: If we understood what you really want to do (i.e. the reason why you are asking) we could suggest better or simpler solution. I find few reasons to change ELF executables on Linux (especially if they are free software, changing the source is a lot easier).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm learning assembly so learning how to play around with these kinds of stuffs is the sole reason. Sorry about that.

Comment: Read more about ELF format, start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you remove a chunk of binary file without adjusting file headers accordingly, it will become invalid.

Fortunately, you can replace instructions with `NOP` without actually removing them. File size remains the same, and if there is no checksum or signature (or if it's not actually checked), there is nothing more to do.

There is no universal way to insert the instructions, but generally you overwrite the original code with a   `JMP` to another location, where you reproduce what the original code did, do your own things as you wanted, then `JMP` back. Finding room for your new code might be impossible without changing the size of the binary, so I would instead patch the code after executable is loaded (perhaps using a special `LD_PRELOAD`ed library).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just replace it with a `NOP` instruction (`0x90`) - or multiple ones if the instruction spans across multiple bytes. This is an old trick.