# Removing assembly instructions from ELF

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, elf

I am working on an obfuscated binary as a part of a crackme challenge. It has got a sequence of `push`, `pop` and `nop` instructions (which repeats for thousands of times). Functionally, these chunks do not have any effect on the program. But, they make generation of CFGs and the process of reversing, very hard.

There are solutions on how to change the instructions to nop so that I can *remove* them. But in my case, I would like to completely strip off those instructions, so that I can get a better view of the CFG. If instructions are stripped off, I understand that the memory offsets must be modified too. As far as I could see, there were no tools available to achieve this directly.

I am using IDA Pro evaluation version. I am open to solutions using other reverse engineering frameworks too. It is preferable, if it is scriptable.

I went through a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903823/how-to-add-remove-x86-instruction-in-linux-executables-without-spoiling-the-alig) but, the proposed solution is not applicable in my case.

Comment: There is r2 (radare.org) framework for unix world with scripting, CLI, WEB, simple TUI and not-yet-finished GUI. You may also try asking at http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's not always possible to do this.  It's possible for code to depend on relative offsets of things in ways that are hard to detect automatically.  (e.g. more complex than just fixing up displacements on jump addresses that cross the removed insns).  But I guess it's worth trying to see if it works without breaking the program.

Comment: Or I guess, I should just look for ways to discard considering parts of code (like the chinks of `push`, `pop`, `nop` sequences) while generating CFG. Should I edit the question to address that or should I open a new one?

Comment: You could consider inserting a `jmp` from the start of the effective NOPs to the end of the NOPs..  At least your IDA display would look more logical.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Thanks. That is a very neat idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I would like to completely strip off those instructions ... I understand that the memory offsets must be modified too ...

In general, this is practically impossible:

1. If the binary exports any dynamic symbols, you would have to update the `.dynsym` (these are probably the offsets you are thinking of).
2. You would have to find every statically-assigned function pointer, and update it with the new address, but there is no effective way to find such pointers.
3. Computed `GOTO`s and switch statements create function pointer tables even when none are present in the program source.
4. As Peter Cordes pointed out, it's possible to write programs that use delta between two assembly labels, and use such deltas (small immediate values directly encoded into instructions) to control program flow.

It's possible that your target program is free from all of the above complications, but spending much effort on a technique that only works for that one program seems wasteful.